# What is the collapse function, L, explained in Ethereum yellow paper?

Tags: ethereum-design

I have learned the Ethereum yellow paper. In the 4th page of the paper, you can find the following statements:

[image: Ethereum Yellow Paper Page 4]
The function, L_s of sigma is defined as p of a, and the function is used to provide a short identity. I wonder whether if L_s is a function which outputs some value (a hash) or a set of tuples of p(a) like in the picture?

What is the collapse function? And how do I understand the function L_s?

Answer (score 1):

The collapse function returns a set of tuples, each representing the following: the hash of an address A (first component), followed by the serialization of the state of that address, i.e., the Recursive Length Prefix (RLP) of that A's nonce, balance, storage, and code hash.